# Encode the spaces in url using url:encode() method in Ballerina lang

Tags: string, replace, encoding, ballerina

In Ballerina language, can the url:encode() function be used to selectively **encode only spaces** in a URL?

For example I need to do the following

```
'https://example.com/one two three' -------> 'https://example.com/one%20two%20three'
```

I'm using the ballerina version 2201.8.0 (Swan Lake Update 8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to selectively encode only spaces in a URL using the url:encode() function. However, ballerina regex can be used to replace the spaces with another character. For example, the following code snippet replaces all spaces in a URL with the `%20` string.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    string url = "https://example.com/one two three";
    string encodedUrl = re` `.replaceAll(url, "%20");
    io:println(encodedUrl);
}
```